# How to receive and use NSErrorPointer

Tags: swift, nserror

I'm not asking how to pass an NSErrorPointer to a function, but rather how to receive it and use it. I couldn't find any documentation on this whatsoever. Something like this:

```
func doSomething(error: NSErrorPointer) {
    error = NSError(...);
}
```

The code above gives

> Cannot assign to 'let' value 'error'

Comment: "I couldn't find any documentation on this whatsoever" -- then you ***really really really*** need to learn how to use Google. It's right on the first page, aka the official documentation on Apple Developer: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: This is the page I get: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look into the headers you can see that `NSErrorPointer` is:

```
typealias NSErrorPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>
```

Which is:

```
struct AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<T> : Equatable, LogicValue {
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool

    /// Access the underlying raw memory, getting and
    /// setting values.
    var memory: T
}
```

So you must check the logic value and then set memory, like this:

```
if error != nil {
    error.memory = NSError(...)
}
```

Also mentioned here: [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: I see. Not the best documentation page title I've seen. Never would have guessed that's were to look. Thanks.

Comment: It's the first link I get for 'set NSErrorPointer value' on google ... Also, by command-clicking 'NSErrorPointer' you would get to the declarations I pasted

Comment: It's the first page I get too, but it didn't seem like what I was looking for... I must have skipped it. Even now I still think they could have chosen a better place for this...